# Change the HTML of the comment form that is generating somewhere from the core Wordpress

Tags: functions, comments, comments-template

[image]

The above is a snapshot where some classes and HTML arrangements(**some flex and flexbox arrangements are needed**) are generated by the WordPress →

```
<cite class="fn"></cite>
<span class="say"></span>
```

but unless I put in some div arrangement I can't implement the HTML design to my WordPress comment system →

```
<div class="some-class">
    <cite class="fn"></cite>
    <span class="say"></span>    
</div>
```

I am sure that there must be certain way to achieve this(Modify the core comment form HTML).

Comment: It depends entirely on the theme, as it can create its own template anywhere and and call it anything. Look for a file called comments.php in the theme folder, but if you're using a custom theme - which it appears you are - there's no way for us to help without knowing more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own custom HTML structure for comment listing. Inside your `comments.php` file, there will be a call to [`wp_list_comments()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) function. Find it, and pass your own function as its callback:

```
wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'my_function' ) );
```

Now, create a callback function and start implementing your own HTML structure. This function accepts 3 arguments. Here is a basic example:

```
my_function( $comment, $args, $depth ){
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    // You have access to comment's ID and other
    // comment query methods here, such as comment_ID();
}
```

Comment: Its just like creating short-code, Right? and then pass the output in between this →         `ob_start();
return ob_get_clean();`

Comment: should I delete the default arguments inside the array → https://www.screencast.com/t/xktwJHG7uv?

Comment: There's no need to delete them, or use output buffering. The link to codex page contains an example of how this function works. You can `echo` content too.